# How to compare two models?

Tags: statistical-significance, model, model-comparison

I have two models. The variable x is the same for both models (time). The dependent variable (y) is a measure taken in one model with the left hand and in other model with the right hand.

I want to know if they are significantly different from each other. I searched but I think I can't use ANOVA() right? I don't know how to proceed!

Thank you,
Inês

---

I did measures A on one hand and measures B on the other. So I have model1: measures A ~ time, and model2: measures B ~time

Comment: Did you measure each subject on one hand only, or on both?

Comment: I did measures A on one hand and measures B on the other. So I have model1: measures A ~ time, and model2: measures B ~time

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? As @StephanKolassa alluded to, it is important to know whether the same subjects provided data for both left and right hands. It is also equally important to know what "time" represents. Is it a binary indicator (e.g., distinguishing pre and post)? Or is it something like a measure of reaction time?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what "measures A" and "measures B" are. Did you measure two different things? Plus, I'm still unclear on whether you measured each subject on only one hand or on both.

Comment: I will try to give more context: x variable is time (in minutes). We do the measurements after 5 min, 10 min, ...
y variable: we measure first on one hand, and then on the other hand. I want to compare the results.

Comment: I think you should combine the models and then add a variable for "hand".